# Ordered List not printing number 1, but all other numbers. why?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Hey guy's I am doing fixing a style that was messed up in IE, but everything looks nice in the browser, however when I go to print it doesn't show # 1, from 2 thereafter. What is the issue. Please help me. Thanks

[image]

**The css**

```
ol.printplanitemlist
{
 list-style-type:decimal;
 margin-top:1em;
 margin-bottom:1em;
 padding-left:2.5em;
 border:0;
 line-height:100%;

}
ol.printplanitemlist li
{
    /* margin-bottom:1em;*/
    margin-bottom:1em;
    position:relative; 

}

.ActivityPromptText {

}

ul.PlanItemDisplay li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
}

ul.PlanItemDisplay
{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}


.MedicationTitle, .MedicationDescription, .MedicationName, .MedicationClass, .MedicationStrength, .MedicationForm, .MedicationHowOften, .MedicationMoreInfo {

    top:-17px;

}

ul, li
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}


.printLbl {
    font-size:1em;
    /*line-height:1.375em;*/
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    margin-bottom:0.188em;
}

li.ActivityTitle, li.AnnouncementTitle, li.MeasurementTitle, li.MedicationTitle,
li.QuestionTitle
{
    color:#999999; font-size:0.75em; font-weight:bold; line-height:1.125em; margin-bottom:-0.188em; margin-top:0.5em; font-style:normal; display:block;
}

 .AnnouncementPlanItemDisplay, .MeasurementPlanItemDisplay, .QuestionPlanItemDisplay{
    top:-0.969em;
    position:relative;
    line-height:1.375em;
}


ul#ActivityDisplay {

    position:relative;
    top:-1.188em;
```

}

```
<FORM id=form1 method=post name=form1 action=PrintCarePlan.aspx>
<DIV><INPUT id=__EVENTTARGET type=hidden name=__EVENTTARGET> <INPUT id=__EVENTARGUMENT type=hidden name=__EVENTARGUMENT> <INPUT id=__VIEWSTATE value=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 type=hidden name=__VIEWSTATE> </DIV>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript src="/WebResource.axd?d=1HwPIkddnYckUN2xUQU95T2VKatY6mt9Dg990zejInCszK3pN-A9sNz55sulwawon9MvfVMYNaagWXGXXyUS4KFjvzU1&amp;t=634208670757546466"></SCRIPT>

<DIV><INPUT id=__PREVIOUSPAGE value=RYBDuzinhGYBVohg1mfRtZqBqjrEl1IOfB1y5sMq5HRkm5gPpG_IN9UuYjxeqh4EtESSJfV_5g0lFzfooz8hR_0lGvGxoJWHmR-0aPBDV6VBLTZm0 type=hidden name=__PREVIOUSPAGE> <INPUT id=__EVENTVALIDATION value=/wEWAwLr0OzxDgKL1Z6VCgKyq56pB3ifZrQiaUnVJyYeWgMXmhiu4qtR type=hidden name=__EVENTVALIDATION> </DIV>
<DIV class=container>
<DIV class=header><INPUT style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" id=logo onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("logo", "", false, "", "Home.aspx", false, false))' src="../Images/logo.png" type=image name=logo> </DIV>
<DIV>
<P></P>
<DIV class=masterHeading>Care Plan For on 1/13/2011<BR></DIV><BR><BR>
<P></P><BR></DIV>
<DIV>
<TABLE style="MARGIN-LEFT: auto; MARGIN-RIGHT: auto" border=0 cellSpacing=5 cellPadding=0 width="90%">
<TBODY>
<TR vAlign=top>
<TD><LABEL class=printLbl>Additional information for today:</LABEL><BR>
<OL class=printplanitemlist>
<LI>
<UL class="PlanItemDisplay AnnouncementPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccAnnouncement_liTitle class=AnnouncementTitle><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccAnnouncement_Title>TED stockings</SPAN> 
<LI class=AnnouncementMsg><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccAnnouncement_AnnouncementMsg>Please where your TED (Thrombo Embolic Deterrent) stockings throughout the day. You may remove them at night.</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL class="PlanItemDisplay AnnouncementPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl01_ccAnnouncement_liTitle class=AnnouncementTitle><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl01_ccAnnouncement_Title>pain medication before exercise</SPAN> 
<LI class=AnnouncementMsg><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl01_ccAnnouncement_AnnouncementMsg>Please take your pain medication 30 minutes before you start your exercise</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL class="PlanItemDisplay AnnouncementPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl02_ccAnnouncement_liTitle class=AnnouncementTitle><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl02_ccAnnouncement_Title>towel under ankle</SPAN> 
<LI class=AnnouncementMsg><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl02_ccAnnouncement_AnnouncementMsg>It is important that you place a towel roll under your ankle when you are lying in bed</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL class="PlanItemDisplay AnnouncementPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl03_ccAnnouncement_liTitle class=AnnouncementTitle><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl03_ccAnnouncement_Title>blood clot</SPAN> 
<LI class=AnnouncementMsg><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl01_rPlanItems_ctl03_ccAnnouncement_AnnouncementMsg>If you have any of these symptoms, please contact the office immediately. * Changes in skin color (redness) in one leg * Increased warmth in one leg * Leg pain in one leg * Leg tenderness in one leg * Swelling (edema) of one leg</SPAN> </LI></UL></LI></OL><BR></TD></TR>
<TR vAlign=top>
<TD><LABEL class=printLbl>My Medications:</LABEL><BR>
<OL class=printplanitemlist>
<LI>
<UL class="PlanItemDisplay MedicationPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl02_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMedication_liTitle class=MedicationTitle><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl02_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMedication_Title>pain reliever</SPAN> 
<LI class=MedicationName><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl02_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMedication_Name>ibuprofen</SPAN> 
<LI class=MedicationClass>(<SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl02_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMedication_MedicationClass>caplets</SPAN>) 
<LI class=MedicationStrength><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl02_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMedication_Strength>800 mg</SPAN> 
<LI class=MedicationForm><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl02_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMedication_Form></SPAN>, 
<LI class=MedicationHowOften><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl02_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMedication_HowOften>Take 1 caplet every 4-6 hours as needed</SPAN> </LI></UL></LI></OL><BR></TD></TR>
<TR vAlign=top>
<TD><LABEL class=printLbl>My Activities:</LABEL><BR>
<OL class=printplanitemlist>
<LI>
<UL style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; CLEAR: left; LEFT: 0px" id=ActivityDisplay class="PlanItemDisplay MedicationPlanItemDisplay">
<LI class=ActivityPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl03_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccActivity_ActivityText>Please walk with your assistive device (walker/cane or crutches) on a flat surfaces within your house for 15 minutes 5 times per day</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; CLEAR: left; LEFT: 0px" id=ActivityDisplay class="PlanItemDisplay MedicationPlanItemDisplay">
<LI class=ActivityPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl03_rPlanItems_ctl01_ccActivity_ActivityText>Please walk up and down stairs 3 times today WITH ASSISTANCE ONLY. Always use a device and a rail. If you do not have stairs, disregard this</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; CLEAR: left; LEFT: 0px" id=ActivityDisplay class="PlanItemDisplay MedicationPlanItemDisplay">
<LI class=ActivityPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl03_rPlanItems_ctl02_ccActivity_ActivityText>Please use ice as needed today. Be certain to use it after exercising as well</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; CLEAR: left; LEFT: 0px" id=ActivityDisplay class="PlanItemDisplay MedicationPlanItemDisplay">
<LI class=ActivityPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl03_rPlanItems_ctl03_ccActivity_ActivityText>Please massage the area around your incision several times today</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; CLEAR: left; LEFT: 0px" id=ActivityDisplay class="PlanItemDisplay MedicationPlanItemDisplay">
<LI class=ActivityPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl03_rPlanItems_ctl04_ccActivity_ActivityText>Please use the stationary recombent bike today for 10 minutes. Start with partial revolutions and progress to full revolutions as tolerated.</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; CLEAR: left; LEFT: 0px" id=ActivityDisplay class="PlanItemDisplay MedicationPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl03_rPlanItems_ctl05_ccActivity_liEquipment class=ActivityEquipment><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl03_rPlanItems_ctl05_ccActivity_Equipment>CAMOped</SPAN> 
<LI class=ActivityPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl03_rPlanItems_ctl05_ccActivity_ActivityText>Use CAMOped twice a day for 30 minutes.</SPAN> </LI></UL></LI></OL><BR></TD></TR>
<TR vAlign=top>
<TD><LABEL class=printLbl>My Questions:</LABEL><BR>
<OL class=printplanitemlist>
<LI>
<UL class="PlanItemDisplay QuestionPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl04_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccQuestion_liTitle class=QuestionTitle><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl04_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccQuestion_Title>How are you feeling today?</SPAN> 
<LI class=QuestionPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl04_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccQuestion_PromptText>How are you feeling today?</SPAN> </LI></UL></LI></OL><BR></TD></TR>
<TR vAlign=top>
<TD><LABEL class=printLbl>My Measurements:</LABEL><BR>
<OL class=printplanitemlist>
<LI>
<UL class="PlanItemDisplay MeasurementPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl05_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMeasurement_liTitle class=MeasurementTitle><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl05_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMeasurement_Title>Knee Motion</SPAN> 
<LI class=MeasurementPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl05_rPlanItems_ctl00_ccMeasurement_PromptText>How much can you bend your knee?</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL class="PlanItemDisplay MeasurementPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl05_rPlanItems_ctl01_ccMeasurement_liTitle class=MeasurementTitle><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl05_rPlanItems_ctl01_ccMeasurement_Title>pain level</SPAN> 
<LI class=MeasurementPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl05_rPlanItems_ctl01_ccMeasurement_PromptText>Please log your pain level today</SPAN> </LI></UL>
<LI>
<UL class="PlanItemDisplay MeasurementPlanItemDisplay">
<LI id=rItemHeaders_ctl05_rPlanItems_ctl02_ccMeasurement_liTitle class=MeasurementTitle><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl05_rPlanItems_ctl02_ccMeasurement_Title>range of motion</SPAN> 
<LI class=MeasurementPromptText><SPAN id=rItemHeaders_ctl05_rPlanItems_ctl02_ccMeasurement_PromptText>Please measure your ability to bend and straighten your operative knee</SPAN> </LI></UL></LI></OL><BR></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><!--- indicates the date that the plan is currently displaying ---><INPUT id=hidDisplayedDate type=hidden name=hidDisplayedDate> </DIV>
<DIV class=footer>Copyright © 2008 - <SPAN id=lblCopyrightEndYear>2011</SPAN> iGetBetter, Inc. All rights reserved. </DIV></DIV></FORM>
```

Comment: a link to the site would help greatly.

Comment: running locally sry. added the css for convenience

Comment: You have provided completely insufficient information for others to answer the question.

Comment: I cannot duplicate the problem by copying your CSS into a JSFiddle and creating an `<ol class="printplanitemlist">` with three items inside. If you can provide an actual, working (well, broken, I guess) bit of HTML that has the same error, then we can help.

Comment: Question sense title not has the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed all the attached css and start rebuilding the styles from scratch. Apparently there was a few styles that were overriding other styles and adding additional properties to the page (darn coders!), but everything is sorted. Thanks for all who responded. it was very much appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your post but if the issue only happens when you print the page, then you could try creating a print-only stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

You may be able to solve this issue that way by providing some sort of different styling to the element (and possibly the element to the left or above that may be masking the number).

Comment: yea i do have a different style sheet. it's included above

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on jsFiddle, and the ordered lists are displayed correctly - http://jsfiddle.net/LwtkW/

Comment: I can give you this, your code is really hard to read and get a grip - the all caps made my eyeballs burn :-)

Comment: the display is not the problem, it's the print out